# Implementing an Object type in C++

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

I'm currently working through the "[Crafting Interpreters](https://craftinginterpreters.com/)" book by Robert Nystrom. He uses Java to implement the visitor pattern in which the visitor functions return the Object type. C++ doesn't support an Object type so my solution was to create a polymorphic type in c++ using virtual functions and inheritance

I'm just curious about the drawbacks of my implementation and how it could be implemented better:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Object {
public:
    virtual std::string getType() const = 0;
};

class String : public Object {
private:
    std::string value;

public:
    String(const std::string& val) : value(val) {}

    std::string getType() const override {
        return "string";
    }

    std::string getValue() const {
        return value;
    }
};

class Double : public Object {
private:
    double value;

public:
    Double(double val) : value(val) {}

    std::string getType() const override {
        return "double";
    }

    double getValue() const {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `std::variant` instead

With your code you have to write a visitor like this:

```
Object* object = new Double(3.1415);

if (object->getType() == "string") {
    std::cout << static_cast<String*>(object)->getValue();
} else if (object->getType() == "double") {
    std::cout << static_cast<Double*>(object)->getValue();
}
```

Which is very tedious (especially as you add more types), inefficient, and doesn't have type safety, as you can accidentally `static_cast<>()` to the wrong type and the compiler won't notice. You also need to work with pointers a lot, which means you have to be careful to `delete` them where appropriate, or use the right smart pointers.

C++17 introduced [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to solve this in a type safe way, and allows for an easier way to [visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) it. For example, you can write:

```
using Object = std::variant<std::string, double>;
…
Object object = 3.1415;

std::visit([](auto& value) {
    std::cout << value;
}, object);
```